# Debugging a Runtime 3061 error (Help Request) Access VBA

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

Ok I am working on a Database in microsoft access and I need some assistance with finding the problem in some of my VBA code for a particular form.

Below is the VBA code that I am having the problem with and I have Bolded the line which is triggering the error. I think the issue is in the sql statement. I am getting a Runtime Error 3061: too few parameters expected 1

```
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As String
y = Me.GLStringID
**Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(GLStringID) AS Total FROM LCDAList WHERE GLStringID='"y"';")**
x = rst!Total
```

If anyone could help me I would be most greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Your quotes are wrong around your '"Y"'. Remove the double quotes, so that the statement is</strike>

You've changed the entire problem after getting an answer. Please don't do that - it makes the answer wrong, and the person who answered look foolish.

After your change, the problem is that you're not properly concatenating (combining) your query and your variable `y`. In VBA, the string concatenation operator is `&`. Something like this should work:

```
"SELECT COUNT(GLStringID) AS Total FROM LCDAList WHERE GLStringID = '" & y & "';"
```

So your code line should be:

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(GLStringID) AS Total FROM LCDAList WHERE GLStringID = '" & y & "';")
```

Comment: Thank you that was extremely helpful. it got me past that error but I have run into another error from the over arching form this is part of. let me post the full code;

Comment: `Private Sub Location_Change()`
`     Dim strSql As String`
`     Dim rst As Recordset`
`     Dim x As Integer`
`     Dim y As String`
`     y = Me.GLStringID`
`     Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(GLStringID) AS Total FROM LCDAList WHERE GLStringID='y';")`
`     x = rst!Total`
`     If x < 1 Then`
`         strSql = "INSERT INTO LCDAList VALUES(me.GLStringID, me.Location, me.Client, me.Department, me.Account);"`
`         DoCmd.RunSQL strSql`
`     End If`
` End Sub`

Comment: That's a totally different question, and it belongs in a new question. I've answered the question asked here, which was about the runtime error. Ask your new one in a totally new question, just like you did this one; you can properly format it there, and explain the new problem you're having.